# Import data from Ms Project to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, vsto, ms-project

I am creating a routine in Excel VBA, which opens an MS Project file and copies the information from the selected columns to Excel through a for loop iterating through the tasks. The problem is that since it is a cycle and it goes from task to task, the processing speed is slow.

This is the cycle used to go through the tasks and copy the information into excel.

```
   i = 2 
    For Each Tarea In Proj.Tasks
        Ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = Tarea.WBS 
        Ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = Tarea.OutlineLevel 
        Ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = Tarea.Summary 'Resumen
        Ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = Tarea.Name 'Nombre de tarea
        Ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = Tarea.Duration
        Ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = Tarea.Start
        Ws.Cells(i, 7).Value = Tarea.Finish
        Ws.Cells(i, 8).Value = Tarea.Predecessors
        Ws.Cells(i, 9).Value = Tarea.Successors
        Ws.Cells(i, 10).Value = Tarea.Milestone
        Ws.Cells(i, 11).Value = Tarea.Critical
        Ws.Cells(i, 12).Value = Tarea.ResourceNames
        Ws.Cells(i, 13).Value = Tarea.Work
        i = i + 1
    Next Tarea
```

No hassle, it works...but it's very slow if the schedule has a lot of activities. Is there the possibility that from Excel VBA you can execute a copy of the range in Ms Project and then paste it in Excel by means of a command?... the above is looking for an option to improve the speed of information extraction.

Comment: I ran into the exact same issue when importing task data from Project to Excel: it was insanely slow, especially for large Project schedules. What I created was a two-step process to export the data from Project, then import that data into Excel. Because data in MS Project is very structured, I chose JSON as a structured way to collect that data (rather than direct arrays or VBA classes). Additionally, the JSON has the option of writing the Project data to a JSON file as an intermediate step if needed (which I did occasionally use).  YMMV

Comment: Hello, unfortunately due to requirements I have to generate this solution in Excel and for this VBA works wonders for me, but it limits me due to processing speed (as in this case). Thank you for your words, but that solution does not apply to me at the moment.